# VBA Authorization oauth2 API

Tags: json, vba, ms-access, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-401

Been stuck on this for a few days now.
Trying to obtain access token from an API with oauth2 authentication.

But I keep getting '401 Unauthorized',
"Full authentication is required'

My gues is i'm doing something wrong with the

```
 .SetRequestHeder "Authorization", "basic " + (base64 encoded)
```

Here's the code so far: (worked with another API)

```
Username = "myusername"
Password = "myclientsecret"

PasswordnUsername = Password & ":" & Username

    argumentString = "?grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=mypassword"

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", "https://api.url/partner/oauth/token", False
    xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "basic " + mdl_API_MB_ACCESS_TOKEN.Base64Encode(PasswordnUsername)
    xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "x-api-key", "myxapicode"
    xmlhttp.Send (argumentString)
```

Comment: Solved, api key provided by the supplier was wrong. *eye-roller*